# Cloud Foundry: Unknown App crash reason: exit_description: Downloading failed

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

In the night of December 9 crashed an app in our Swisscom Application Cloud with the following description:

```
2017-12-09T05:26:22.00+0100  app.crash  my_app   index: 0, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: Downloading failed
```

Does anyone know exactly what this exit description means?

Buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack, 
APP: MVC based App written in object oriented PHP, 
Nothing special in manifest.yml config

Comment: please edit your question with more info. What buildpack you use? Manifest.yml? More info about your app. Please also use code tags. Thanks

Comment: I can't tell you very much because there's not much information to go on here but "downloading failed" usually means something the Diego Cell needed to run your application, probably the droplet, couldn't be downloaded.  Your platform operator would need to investigate more.

Comment: I don't have more info than I've just added.

Comment: Did you have any result about this issue?

Comment: OK. I just updated diego-release version and it was fixed. It confused me because I could not find any error message.